# twitter4j.properties not reflecting changes made

Tags: twitter4j

I read that from Jan 14th 2014, twitter only supports https://api.twitter.com.
We use twitter4j library to access twitter apis and see that the restBaseURL in this library still uses http instead of https.

One of the forum suggested, I could set 
restBaseURL=https://api.twitter.com/
in the twitter4j.properties(this exists in my classpath) and the change would be pickedup.

But this doesnt happen. Did anyone come across this issue.

Comment: i see that if the "restBaseURL=https://api.twitter.com/1.1" it gets picked up but not if it is "restBaseURL=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/" (without "").

Comment: false alarm..this doesnt work. I'm using twitter4j 3.0.2 version

Answer (score 0):

In my Android app I had this issue with Twitter4J Core 3.0.3. And configuration changes not being used.

I have just updated to Twitter4J Core 3.0.5 and I don't need to set configuration as the new build points to Twitters API using https. Hope that helps.